# webview_shell on AOSP 7.1.2 emulator crashes, failed to create a pbuffer surface

Tags: android-emulator, android-webview, android-source

I built an aosp_x64-eng emulator and want to test its webview, but it crashes immediately after launching. According to logcat, it says that `[FATAL:gpu_info_collector_android.cc(193)] failed to create a pbuffer surface for fetching driver strings, EGL_SUCCESS (3000)`.

A [link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/83423/webview-on-android-7-0-crashes) said the problem can be fixed by switching the CPU/ABI in the AVD from "Intel Atom (x86_64)" to "Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)". How can I change that in an AOSP emulator?

Any other suggestions? Thank you for your time:-)

Comment: emualtor -gpu host